# Coin tossed n times, sequence never has head followed by head

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed $n$ times. Let $p_n$ be the probability that the sequence of tosses never has a head followed by a head.

Show that
$$p_n =\frac12 p_{n−1} + \frac14 p_{n−2}.$$
Find $p_n$ using the conditions $p_0 = p_1 = 1$.

Comment: Is it homework? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Any valid sequence of length $n$ starts with a tail ($T$), then it is followed by a valid sequence of length $n-1$, or starts with a head followed by a tail ($HT$), then it is followed by a valid sequence of length $n-2$. This gives:
$$ p_n = \frac{1}{2}p_{n-1}+\frac{1}{4}p_{n-2}. $$
Since $p_1=1$ and $p_2=\frac{3}{4}$ and the previous line gives:
$$ p_n = A\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^n+B\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^n,$$
it follows that:

> $$ p_n = \left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^n+\left(\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- If the last two tosses are not two heads then either

  - the last toss was a tail, or
  - the last toss was a head and the previous toss was a tail
- At the start, the last toss (which never actually happened) was not a head, so treat it as if it were a tail.
- If you work out the probabilities for the initial values, you will find they look like Fibonacci numbers divided by powers of $2$.  You can then prove this by induction and give an exact result